# How to add more rows using an "Add" button in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I currently have a form created in "Jotform" in which I use the "Configurable List" widget. I would like to replicate this same effect of adding and removing rows in Oracle Apex. How can I do this?

Obs.: I found a plugin by Rodrigo Mesquita that does exactly that, but only with one field. I need two or more fields.

[My form from Jotform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z18H4.png)

[My Form from Apex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPsrx.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you probably shouldn't reinvent the wheel and - instead - create a region whose type is **Interactive Grid**. Functionality (you're talking about) is built-in into it. There's the "Add Row" button which does the job.

Comment: Completely agree. Try to stick to the available native components - it will save you a lot of time now when developing and later for upgrades.

Comment: I really understand what you mean about native components of APEX. But I may have explained it wrong. I need to do this action inside a form. I already have other fields before and after the fields shown in the image.

Comment: It is still Interactive Grid, in a master-detail relationship with other data on the form.

Comment: I did with Interactive grid. I had to create another table to store the data. Thanks for the advice guys!